# Book in which 'Genius' children created programs

Tags: story-identification, books

Trying to find out what the series was where there was a child that created 'Guard dog programs" and another something called the 'dragon?' I remember a bank being involved in the first part of the book but that's about all.

Comment: In the first Ender book (Ender's game), the kids designed guard dog programs to secure their 'desks' (what we would now call tablets), and Ender later commanded the Dragon army.. But the closest I can think of.

Comment: The mention of genius children would seem strongly in favour too.

Answer (score 4):

Per KHW's comment above, I think the book you're referring to is [Ender's Game](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/375802.Ender_s_Game) by Orson Scott Card.

**There's an explicit reference to "Genius Children";**

> "Very funny." Mother said. "I try to be concerned, but it makes no
>   difference to my **genius children**.”

**Ender creates a Security system which he gives out to his friends;**

> Alai grinned. "I just got in and trashed somebody's files. He's right
>   behind me on cracking the system. I need protection, Ender. I need
>   your system.” "If I give you my system, you'll know how I do it and
>   you'll get in and trash me.” "You say me?" Alai asked. "I the sweetest
>   friend you got!” Ender laughed. "I'll setup a system for you.”

**Ender commands the Dragon army;**

> Dragon, said the form. There was no Dragon Army. "I've never heard of
>   Dragon Army," Ender said. "That's because there hasn't been a Dragon
>   Army in four years. We discontinued the name because there was a
>   superstition about it"..."Well, why are you reviving it now?” "We had
>   a lot of extra uniforms to use up.”

The bank reference is a bit harder to clear up. There is a mention of Ender having "*plenty of salary that [he] never used, sitting around in banks*" but that's right at the end of the book. More likely you're thinking of Ender's sister and brother needing their father's **citizen card** in order to falsify their identities on the internet.

[image: Ender's Game]